# detecting the end of video using jwplayer?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

im using jwplayer with thier javascript api, im trying to detect when its the end of the video 
at the moment i have tried this:

```
onTime: function(event) {
          console.log(this.getDuration());
          console.log(this.getPosition());
          if (this.getPosition() === this.getDuration()) {
            return alert("Im done");
          }
        }
```

but this alerts twice with "im done", and obviously this is not an efficient way to detect the end of the video?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [onComplete(callback)](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference).

```
onComplete: function() {
    return alert("Im done");
}
```

Comment: Complete reference - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference

Comment: Oops, missed that it was hyperlinked :) D'oh!